# Fill in missing values in data table with linear interpolation? (python)

Tags: python, list, for-loop, interpolation

Say I have a data set like this:

```
DAY     DATA
1       4
2       6
3       8
4       6
5       nan
6       nan
7       nan
8       2
9       4
10      nan
11      6
```

And I would like to fill in the nan values in the DATA column with the y = mx+b line connecting the two nearest non-nan values on either side. For instance, days 5, 6, and 7 would have the values 5, 4, and 3 respectively, and 10 would have the value 5. How could I do this with a for loop, for instance? Or any other way?

It seems pretty simple, here is what I have tried so far:

```
for i in range(len(DAY)):
    if math.isnan(DATA[i]):
        for j in range(i+1,len(DAY)):
            if not math.isnan(DATA[j]):
                print(DATA[i-1],DATA[j])
```

I am just trying to get it to print the two values on either side of the nan sequences (to start), but that does not work, instead it gives me the first of the nan sequence then every other number after the nan sequence until then next nans, etc...

Comment: Try: `df['DATA'] = df['DATA'].interpolate()`

Comment: While you can just interpolate as @enke suggests, I think there's benefit to understanding how to write code to do the interpolation and you're very close. You  need a `break` in your second `if` statement so that once you get the value, it stops. That will terminate the for statement once you have found a non-NaN value in your second loop. Of course, there are many different ways you could write this code. I'm just suggesting how to stick with what you've developed so far.

Comment: I had to do a very similar thing.  It's an interesting problem.  My advice would be to make sure that either end has no Nan on it (deal with them specially, if needed).  And then you can just iterate through the whole table.  Interpolate between the closest entries that have values to create your new value.